# How to access the second span in the below code?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to access a span with the date in but when I write article.h3.span, it gives the first span (/). How can I access a span with the date?

```
 <a class="category-link" href="https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news_category/world/">
  World
 </a>
 <span>
  /
 </span>
 <a class="category-link" href="https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news_category/crime-legal-world/">
  Crime &amp; Legal
 </a>
 <span class="right date">
  Mar 19, 2019
 </span>
</h3>
```

below is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
article = "https://www.japantimes.co.jp/tag/cybersecurity/page/1/"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(article)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
article = soup.find('article')
date = article.h3.span.text
print(date)
```

Comment: *but when I write article.h3.span* Where do you write that? Where is your code?

Comment: you need to use the `span` tag instead of `article` and use its class `right date`, see if my answer posted below helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `class=right date` from the `span` tag would do it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

article = "https://www.japantimes.co.jp/tag/cybersecurity/page/1/"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(article)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
date = soup.find('span', class_ ="right date")
print(date.text)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Mar 19, 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next` to get the date, see the code below!

```
html = '''
 <a class="category-link" href="https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news_category/world/">
  World
 </a>
 <span>
  /
 </span>
 <a class="category-link" href="https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news_category/crime-legal-world/">
  Crime &amp; Legal
 </a>
 <span class="right date">
  Mar 19, 2019
 </span>
</h3>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
date = soup.find('span',attrs={'class':'right date'}).next
print(date.strip())
```

Output:

```
Mar 19, 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

For that particular date you can use a faster single class class selector

```
item = soup.select_one('.date').text
```

If you want them all

```
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('.date')]
```