# How to access text from both <p> using beautifulsoup4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to grab text from both `<p>`, how do I get that?
for first `<p>` my code is working but I couldn't able to get the second `<p>`.

```
  <p>
        <a href="https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2019/03/19/world/crime-legal-world/emerging-online-threats-changing-homeland-securitys-role-merely-fighting-terrorism/">
         Emerging online threats changing Homeland Security's role from merely fighting terrorism
        </a>
       </p>
      </hgroup>
     </header>
     <p>
      Homeland Security Secretary Kirstjen Nielsen said Monday that her department may have been founded to combat terrorism, but its mission is shifting to also confront emerging online threats.

    China, Iran and other countries are mimicking the approach that Russia used to interfere in the U.S. ...
      <a class="more_link" href="https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2019/03/19/world/crime-legal-world/emerging-online-threats-changing-homeland-securitys-role-merely-fighting-terrorism/">
       <span class="icon-arrow-2">
       </span>
      </a>
     </p>
```

My code is:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    article = "https://www.japantimes.co.jp/tag/cybersecurity/page/1/"
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(article)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    article = soup.find('div', class_="content_col")
    date = article.h3.find('span', class_= "right date")
    date = date.text
    headline = article.p.find('a')
    headline = headline.text
    content = article.p.text
    print(date, headline,content)
```

Comment: Do you want the complete blog post?

Comment: PS. I see you are using the answer from your previous question in this code, Consider accept an answer from your previously asked question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254337/how-to-access-the-second-span-in-the-below-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `.find_next()`. However, it's not the full article:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


article = "https://www.japantimes.co.jp/tag/cybersecurity/page/1/"
page = requests.get(article)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')


article = soup.find('div', class_="content_col")

date = article.h3.find('span', class_= "right date")
date_text = date.text

headline = article.p.find('a')
headline_text = headline.text

content_text = article.p.find_next('p').text
print(date_text, headline_text ,content_text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the parent id and p selector and index into returned list for required number of paragraphs. You can use the time tag for when posted

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2019/03/19/world/crime-legal-world/emerging-online-threats-changing-homeland-securitys-role-merely-fighting-terrorism/#.XJIQNDj7TX4')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
posted = soup.select_one('time').text
print(posted)
paras = [item.text.strip() for item in soup.select('#jtarticle p')]
print(paras[:2])
```